Issue with Running Essential Project on Windows 10 Server: ClassNotFoundException for Server_Stub
I'm seeking assistance with an issue I encountered while setting up Essential Project on a Windows 10 server. I followed the installation manual carefully, but I ran into a problem when I attempted to run the run_protege_server.sh script.
Here's the error message I received:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.smi.protege.server.Server_Stub
SEVERE: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.smi.protege.server.Server_Stub

This error seems to indicate that the class edu.stanford.smi.protege.server.Server_Stub cannot be found. I've ensured that all required JAR files are in the classpath and that the protege.jar file is present in the specified directory. Despite this, the issue persists.
I have tried the suggested solutions, such as verifying the classpath and checking the presence of the JAR files, but these steps have not resolved the issue.
Has anyone else encountered this problem, or does anyone have insights into what might be causing this ClassNotFoundException? Any help or suggestions for resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
protegewiki
